# How to color the line between two points in DGCharts (macos)

Tags: ios-charts

I am using DGCharts 5.0 with a linechart and want to display a GPS track in Macos. This works fine. What I'm looking for is how to set the color of the line between two points (for example, with an index color for speed) so that I can see the complete track-line as multi-colored line with the particular information of how fast I was on that part of the track.
(I do know how to set the color of the entire line, but that is not my concern)
Does anyone have any ideas, or should this be a feature request?

hein_dd

The question is: can this wish done in DGCharts and I have not found a solution?